# Caption in left margin at the top of tabular

Tags: captions

Could you help me 
I want to remove caption to put it at the left margin for any environment
like this
[image]

I know it is not a good way any advice ? Thank you.
This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openany]{book}

\usepackage{etex}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[OT1,T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{libertine}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[framemethod=default]{mdframed}

\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=2 cm,bottom=2 cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{colortbl}

\usepackage{booktabs} 

\definecolor{monvert}{RGB}{0,0,166}
\definecolor{MOnvert}{RGB}{220,85,22} 
\definecolor{Monvert}{RGB}{122,160,175}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}

\frenchbsetup{StandardLists=true}

\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{rotating}

%macros
\makeatletter

\renewcommand{\fnum@figure}{\color{Monvert}\underline{\small\textbf{\figurename~\thefigure}}}

\makeatother

\DeclareCaptionFormat{llap}{\llap{#1#2}\\ \hspace*{-2.2 cm}%
\begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}%
#3   
 \end{minipage}%
}
\captionsetup{format=llap,labelsep=quad,singlelinecheck=no}

 \begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
 \arrayrulecolor{Monvert}  
\scalebox{0.9}{%
\begin{tabular}{lccccc}
\toprule
&\textbf{Source de variation} & \textbf{\textit{d.d.l}} & \textbf{Somme des carrés}&\textbf{Carré moyen}$\bm{CM= \frac{SC}{d.d.l}}$&\textbf{Rapport }$F$\\
\midrule
&Inter facteur $G$& $K-1$ & $\sum\limits^{K}_{j=1}n_j(\bar{X}_j -\bar{X})^2 = SC_G$&$CM_G =\dfrac{SC_G}{K-1}$&\\
&Intra (résidu)&$N-K$ & &&\\
&Total & $N-1$ & &&\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}
\caption{test d'une figure qui s'allonge et s'allonge et s'allonge jusqu'où ?}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Error   Undefined control sequence `\bm`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Package [`floatrow`](http://ctan.org/pkg/floatrow) provide command `\floatbox`

Here we use `\floatbox[<preamble>]{<captype>}[<width>]{caption}{object}` were:

- In the `<preamble>` we have `\capbeside` which places caption beside float, `\thisfloatsetup` which define some settings for the float.
- With `<captype>` we put `table`.
- `\FBwidth` option in the `width` argument allows usage of natural width of float.

---

**Code**

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openany]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[OT1,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=2 cm,bottom=2 cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\definecolor{monvert}{RGB}{0,0,166}
\definecolor{MOnvert}{RGB}{220,85,22} 
\definecolor{Monvert}{RGB}{122,160,175}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\frenchbsetup{StandardLists=true}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{floatrow}

%macros
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\fnum@figure}{\color{Monvert}\underline{\small\textbf{\figurename~\thefigure}}}
\makeatother

\DeclareCaptionFormat{llap}{\llap{#1#2}\\ \hspace*{-2.2 cm}%
\begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}%
#3   
 \end{minipage}%
}


\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{underlcap}{\underline{#1 #2}}
\DeclareCaptionFont{Monvert}{\color{Monvert}}
\captionsetup{format=llap,labelsep=quad,singlelinecheck=no,labelfont=Monvert,labelformat=underlcap}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}

\begin{table}[h]

\floatbox%
[{\capbeside\thisfloatsetup{capbesideposition={left,top},capbesidewidth=1.4cm}}]{table}
[\FBwidth]
{%
\scalebox{0.8}{\caption{\footnotesize test d'une figure qui s'allonge et s'allonge et s'allonge jusqu'où ?}\label{tab:test}}
}
{%
\arrayrulecolor{Monvert}  

\scalebox{0.8}{%
\begin{tabular}{lcccc}
\toprule
\textbf{Source de variation} & \textbf{\textit{d.d.l}} & \textbf{Somme des carrés}&\textbf{Carré moyen} {\scriptsize $\bm{CM= \frac{SC}{d.d.l}}$}&\textbf{Rapport }$F$\\
\midrule
Inter facteur $G$& $K-1$ & $\sum\limits^{K}_{j=1}n_j(\bar{X}_j -\bar{X})^2 = SC_G$&$CM_G =\dfrac{SC_G}{K-1}$&\\
Intra (résidu)   & $N-K$ & &  &\\
Total            & $N-1$ & &  &\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}
}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

**Result**

[image]